# How to do Parallax scrolling in collectionview swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, parallax

I have a Collectionview and a search bar on the top.There is a view on the top of my search bar.When I scroll up my view should hide and my search bar should come to the top.

Comment: try this : https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader

Comment: And what's the issue you are addressing?

Comment: I have a view with a image.Below that view,I have a collectionview with a search bar.When I scroll up my view is not getting hide.